# How do I fix the following error in Tkinter on __init__ function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

**I'm brand new to Tkinter, and am building a tiny UI for interaction with a ML program. Here's the code I'm using for the UI window I've created:**

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class UI:

    def __init__(self, root):

        root.title("Retirement Savings Estimator")

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.age = IntVar()
        self.age = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=self.age)
        self.age.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text ="Enter your age: ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

        self.yearly_salary = StringVar()
        self.yearly_salary = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=self.yearly_salary)
        self.yearly_salary.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Enter your gross yearly wages: ").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

        for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Press the Calculate button to get your estimate: ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
        action = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", default = "active", command = UI).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
        self.age.focus()
        root.bind('<Return>', action)
        
    def predict_savings(*args, root):
        try:  
            user_age = int(self.age.get())
            yr_salary = float(self.yearly_salary.get())
            estimate = regr.predict(user_age, yr_salary)
            ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Your Estimated Amount to Save For Retirement: " + estimate).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        
root = Tk()   
UI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Here's the error message I'm getting when pressing the 'Calculate' button in the UI window:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jesst\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'
```

I've tried adding 'root' to the predict_savings() function to see if this fixes the issue, and a different error generates. I'm not sure what else to try. Any ideas would be excellent.

Comment: What do you want to do for `command=UI` for the *"Calculate"* button? It doesn't make sense to create instance of the class where the button belongs when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The error is this line of code:

```
action = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", default = "active", command = UI).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
```

You are asking tkinter to create a new instance of `UI` when the button is clicked. However, `UI` is defined to need `root` as one of the parameters. When you click the button, no parameters are passed which is why you get the error.

Since the button exists inside `UI`, and `predict_savings` is inside `UI`, the proper solution is to have the button call `self.predict_savings`. Also, `predict_savings` shouldn't require an argument. It doesn't use the arguments so I see no reason to require them. It does, however, require the `self` parameter like any other class method.

```
    ...
    action = ttk.Button(..., command = self.predict_savings)...
    ...

def predict_savings(self):
    ...
```

Comment: user_age = int(self.age.get())
                   ^^^^
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @toyotaSupra: my answer addresses that here: _"Also, predict_savings ... does, however, require the self parameter like any other class method."_

Answer (score 0):

The line below creates a new instance of the class UI.

```
action = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", default = "active", command = UI).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
```

When we press the "Calculate" button, we expect to see the estimate, not a new window. The estimate function is `self.predict_savings`, so we should replace `command = UI` with `command = lambda: self.predict_savings()`.

```
action = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", default = "active", command = lambda: self.predict_savings()).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
```

Comment: user_age = int(self.age.get())
                   ^^^^
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: The button doesn't need to use `lambda` here, it can be `command=self.predict_savings`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bryan Oakley, attempting to explain about instantiated class using self.

I do not understand what this is `estimate = regr.predict`. The `regr.predict` is defined. I had to remove this.

You had too many an errors.

- Add `self` to `self.mainframe` to every widget.
- Add self in `predict_savings` parameter. No need for this `*args, root`. Also ne need to do with trap `try/ except`.
- Using f=string for `Label`.

Code modified:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class UI:
    def __init__(self, root):

        root.title("Retirement Savings Estimator")

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.age = IntVar()
        self.age = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, width=7, textvariable=self.age)
        self.age.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text ="Enter your age: ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

        self.yearly_salary = StringVar()
        self.yearly_salary = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, width=7, textvariable=self.yearly_salary)
        self.yearly_salary.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Enter your gross yearly wages: ").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

        for child in self.mainframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text="Press the Calculate button to get your estimate: ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
        action = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Calculate", default = "active", command =self.predict_savings).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
        self.age.focus()
        root.bind('<Return>', action)
        
    def predict_savings(self):
        #try:  
        user_age = int(self.age.get())
        yr_salary = float(self.yearly_salary.get())
        estimate = (user_age, yr_salary)
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text=f"Your Estimated Amount to Save For Retirement:  {estimate}").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
        #except ValueError:
            #pass
        
root = Tk()   
app = UI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot after calculated:

[image]